# Can someone post questions or answers in languages other than English on SO?

Tags: discussion

Are posts in other languages allowed in SO?  I came across one such question here:

[session_start() error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205666/session-start-error/20006586#20006586)

Should I raise a flag against this?

Comment: SO is english language site, flag it

Comment: That's also not an answer, it's thanking others for the answers.

Comment: FYI: http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=stack%20overflow%20(in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SO is only for English language, no other languages are allowed here. Yes you can flag to moderator attention.